# Positioning trouble on label text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So

This is what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

This is what I have: http://codepen.io/KieranRigby/pen/QyWZxV.  For the snippet bellow, please use "Full page" view.

```css
label {
 color: #6d6e70;
 bottom: 0;
}
.img-row img {
    width: 100%;
}
.img-row {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container img-row">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-offset-1">
      <img id="img-1" class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/ftaEZS9.png" />
      <label for="img-1">Make your essay</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <img id="img-2" class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/7YUtBZk.png" />
      <label for="img-2">Upload your essay</label>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
      <img id="img-3" class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/Hy84vQC.png" />
      <label for="img-3">Choose your pay</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <img id="img-4" class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/tSqCUuO.png" />
      <label for="img-4">Mentors Check</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <img id="img-5" class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/VmwzHFD.png" />
      <label for="img-5">Receive an email</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /.row -->

</div>
```

How do I get the text labels to sit inline at the bottom?

Comment: They are inline and at the bottom.  Can you please clarify the issue?

Comment: If you see on the image, they all line up horizontally. I need the text to all be in line.

Comment: See: http://imgur.com/TRYhCKt 

The bottom of the text should touch the baseline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Codepen](http://codepen.io/adriancarriger/pen/KVKrpL)

Use absolute positioning on your `img` and `label` to align them on the baseline (similar to this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2015081/5357459)).

### New CSS

```
.col-md-2 {
  height: 250px;
}
.col-md-2 img {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  width: 80%;
}
.col-md-2 label {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

This:

- Gives your `.col-md-2` containers a set height
- Moves your `label` element to the very bottom of its parent `.col-md-2`
- Moves your `img` element 30px above the bottom of its parent `.col-md-2`

The `img` width is set to 80% to give some space between images.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot!